# vaadin cache.html size

Tags: optimization, vaadin, app-startup

Looking into Chrome Developer Tools' Audits tab when launching my Vaadin-based web application, I have been horrified to see that the cache.html file was > 4Mb big! I thought that Vaadin's runtime was at worst a few hundred k's. I need to enable gzip compression, but still... how is it even possible that such a huge file is meant to be sent to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4MB is too big. Make sure you are not using GWT's "draft compilation" as it makes the resulting widgetset huge.

The right size is around 400-600kB (uncompressed). The size depends on what widgets are included in the set. Adding new widgets makes it a little bigger while leaving out some unused widgets makes it smaller. Realistic minimum size is between 200-300kB.

Most important is that you have enabled the gzip encoding on you HTTP server. That way only **80kB to 200kB** is actually transferred to the browser.

See also: http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/163146

Comment: That was it, "draft compilation" was set. Fixed. Thanks!